# What is the difference between a bootstrap program and an OS loader?

Tags: operating-system

I'm a student learning about Operating systems and I cannot differentiate these terms.

What is the difference between a bootstrap program and an OS loader? They seem to do the same thing to me.

Answer (score 1):

The perform the same operation namely get your os or kernel running.

But generally an os loader like grub finds your image on external media: like a hardrive, or maybe network. Reads it into Ram and jumps into it.

A bootloader which is probably what you meant by bootstrap is a much more limited piece of software. It can write an image to flash, make sure it was save correctly, and then switch to the new image thereby updating your software.

When the bootloader starts (on reset) it looks for a sign that the environment wants to load a new image. Generally a button is pressed. If it doesn't see the sign, it goes ahead and runs the OS, or embedded software.

If it does see the sign it receives the new image. Over uart, or spi, or wifi. The bootloader always has 2 images. If an update fails it falls back to the old image. If somehow both images or the bootloader itself are damaged, the device is "bricked"

This is how embedded systems can plan software updates

A bootloader is much simple than an OS loader and generally runs on medium complexity embedded systems up to mobile phones. An OS loader runs on PCs, mainframes (very very rarely) and supercomputers.

A bootstrap is even simpler than a bootloader. It sets up the cpu so it is to call main() in your C program. (or Fortran, or COBOL) Something compiled anyway.

There's a lot of things to do before you can call main. cpu speed, setup up segmentation, initialise interrupts. Finally jump to the address of main()

A bootstrap can only start. It cannot update

A bootloader can update

An OSloader chooses an OS from mass storage.